# Anyway to hack content delivery to automate selections?

Tags: visualforce, content, automation, urlhacking, content-delivery

**Question**

Is there anyway to speed up or automate content deliveries?  At a minimum I'm hoping to be able to default the related object or default the piece of related content.  Anything to avoid duplicating data entry and save a couple clicks.

**Background**

We're rolling out content deliveries and are concerned that Sales Reps aren't going to adopt it given the process for delivering content can be confusing and/or difficult.  We're building an inline visualforce page for Opportunities and Leads that displays relevant pieces of content and are looking to jump them as far through the content delivery process as possible when clicking a piece of content.

I know that their isn't any API access to Content Deliveries but am hoping there might be an inventive way to hack in some basic defaulting, possibly with URL hacking, or maybe some javascript in the sidebar?

**Screenshots**

If the user clicks 'Deliver Content' from the Content Delivery related list they end up here, and then have to search for content.  Maybe we can default the piece of content here?
[image: Click Deliver Content from Opportunity]

If the user clicks 'Deliver Content' from the content they'd like delivered they end up here and have to select the type of object and the name.  Maybe we can default the object type and id/name here?
[image: Click Delivery Content from Content]

Comment: Did you end up discovering any method of automating this process?

Comment: Nada, we put together a design for building our own using heroku, but ended up just scrapping content delivery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [winter 15](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000HMq4AAG) there is now programmatic access to content deliveries.

```
ContentDistribution cd = new ContentDistribution();
cd.name = 'test';
cd.ContentVersionId = '12312132abad';
cd.PreferencesAllowOriginalDownload = false;
cd.PreferencesAllowPDFDownload = false;
cd.PreferencesAllowViewInBrowser = true;
insert cd;

cd = [SELECT DistributionPublicUrl FROM ContentDistribution WHERE ID = :cd.Id];
System.debug(cd.DistributionPublicUrl);
```

Basically you can do anything the standard UI will allow you to do.  There doesn't yet seem to be any official documentation on the object, but you can explore it using workbench.  Just make sure your API version is set to 32

[image: screenshot ContentDistribution Object in workbench]